# Find the positive solutions for $x + 2 \{ x \} = 3 \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the positive solutions for $x + 2 \{ x \} = 3 \lfloor x \rfloor$

---

**attempt:**

Notice that the equation can be rewritten as

$$ x + 2 \{ x\} = 2 \lfloor x \rfloor + x - \{x\}$$
$$ 3 \{x\} = 2 \lfloor x \rfloor  $$

From this we know that $3 \{x\}$ must be even positive integer. But the only $\{x\}$ that makes it integer is $\{ x\} = 1/3$ (but $3\{x\}$ is odd) and $\{x\} = 0$. So there is no positive integer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You forgot about $\{x\}=2/3$.

Comment: so the solution is only $x = 1 + \frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: Yes, @AriefAnbiya, that's the only positive [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2B2frac%28x%29%3D3floor%28x%29)

Comment: Unless, I goofed up badly, the only two solutions, positive, neg or zero are $0$ and $1\frac 23$

Answer (score 0):

Right.  So $\{x\} = \frac k{3}$ where $k= 2 \lfloor x \rfloor$, an integer.

As $0\le \{x\}=\frac k3 < 1$  we have $k=2\lfloor x \rfloor = 0, 1,2$ but  $k$ is even, so $k = 2j =  0, 2; j=\lfloor x \rfloor = 0,1$.

And $x = \lfloor x \rfloor +\{x\} = j + \frac {2j}3$ where $j = 0,1$.

And that's it.  All solution, negative, positive, or zero.

Comment: Did you mean $x=\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}=\dfrac k2 + \dfrac k3 = \dfrac {5k}6$?

Comment: I guess I did.  Or I guess I was imaging a third variable.  I wasn't going for $\frac {5k}{6}$ although that is certainly true.

Comment: Geeps.  Typo and proof reading failers.  I'm all over the place tonight.  But This is now worded to match my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

A more transparent way:

We can write $x$ as $x=n+r$, where $n=\lfloor x \rfloor; ~n \in 0,1,2.. $ and $r=\{x\};~   0 \le r < 1. $

Equation reads as,

$n+r+2r=3n \Rightarrow r= \frac{2n}{3} \Rightarrow  r =0 , \frac {2}{3}.$

so $x=0, \frac{5}{3}$